# UNC-Paths aren't supported

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to color my console outputs, but while doing so ran into the following warning message:

```
CMD.EXE was started with the Path given above as the current Directory.
UNC-Paths aren't supported.
The Windows - Directory will be set as current Directory.
```

That warning comes from this line:

```cpp
hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
```

Does anyone has an idea how I would get rid of that message?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this output has nothing to do with the colors, and is just caused by the way Code::Blocks starts the terminal. Does it appear on a simple "Hello World" too?

Comment: @Quentin No, actually not.
The normal output of it is the Runtime and "press any key"
The Color function adds the ones above, I tested that by commenting the call.

Comment: If you want to learn, don't start with the worst possible IDE to do so. Download [Visual Studio Community](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/) and take it from there. Code::Blocks has poor defaults, a tendency to get in the way of building applications, and is pretty much unsupported.

Comment: @IInspectable 
Yeah, thanks. It's all about the debugger obviously. 
The Error does not occur in Visual Studio...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GetStdHandle is probably returning a handle which is incompatible with the debug console you have running. Calling the function once at program start-up and keeping hold of the handle might work better.

Comment: I just tried Visual Studio ... and wow. It's really just about the Debugger.
Visual Studio has absolute no Problem with it, and the error does not occur. Thanks for helping